# Implementing Autocomplete Functionality in Discord Modals for User Inputs

Tags: discord.js, bots

I am currently developing a Discord bot that utilizes modals for user input. The bot facilitates various actions through buttons, and users are required to input certain values into a modal. However, some of these values can be challenging for users to remember, which can potentially hinder the user experience. To address this, I am looking to implement an autocomplete feature within the Discord modals. This would allow users to receive suggestions as they type, streamlining the process and enhancing usability.

I have conducted extensive research to determine if Discord officially supports an autocomplete feature for modals, but I have not found any relevant information in the official documentation or forums. It appears that such functionality is not natively supported by Discord at this time. I am reaching out to the community to inquire if there is any unofficial workaround or custom implementation that could facilitate this feature. If anyone has insights, alternative approaches, or experience with implementing a similar feature, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to address any **specific problem** you need help on developing the bot.

Answer (score 0):

An exact autocomplete feature like suggestions based on user input as they type is not possible as far as I know. However, you could make use of either .setPlaceholder .setValue property in the TextInputBuilder component of your modal to help your users know what to input.

**.setPlaceholder**

- As the name implies, it adds a placeholder to the field input. You could use that to guide users on which input choices they can make.
- The placeholder can't be too long or else it will throw an error.

**.setValue**

- This adds a predefined value for the field input. You could also use this, however the user needs to clear the value first.